# hyperlink from one cell to another cell

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I want to connect the cell Cells(5, m) to another cell Cells(9,n). If I write

```
Sub macro()

Dim m As Integer
Dim n As Integer
m = 5
n = 2

Dim rga As Range
Set rga = Cells(5, m)
Dim rgb As Range
Set rgb = cells(9,n)

sheet1.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheet1.Cells(5, m), Address:="", SubAddress:="Sheet1!b9"


End Sub
```

It works well but if I write rgb instead of "Sheet1!b9" , that does not work. Is there a way that I can connect two cells that their coordinates are variable?

Comment: `SubAddress:="'" & rgb.Parent.Name & "'!" & rgb.Address(False, False)`

Comment: @TimWilliams Your solution is the best. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution as require below

```
Sub macro()

Dim m As Integer
Dim n As Integer
m = 5
n = 2

Dim rga As Range
Set rga = Sheet1.Cells(5, m)
Dim rgb As Range
Set rgb = Sheet1.Cells(9, n)

rga.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheet1.Cells(5, m), Address:="", SubAddress:="Sheet1!" & NumberToLetter(rgb.Column) & rgb.Row


End Sub

Function NumberToLetter(iCol As Long) As String
   Dim a As Long
   Dim b As Long
   a = iCol
   NumberToLetter = ""
   Do While iCol > 0
      a = Int((iCol - 1) / 26)
      b = (iCol - 1) Mod 26
      NumberToLetter = Chr(b + 65) & NumberToLetter
      iCol = a
   Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much your function is very good too.